# installing rules in openflow

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, openflow

In Openflow, we install rules with priorities. Now suppose we already have two rules installed at a switch, of priority `1` and `2`. And now we want to add another rule, of some priority strictly between `1` and `2` (say `1.5`). What is the usual way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard practice used within networking and defining various rule lists (ACLs, etc) is to number them in increments of 10, so new rules can easily be injects between. The same could apply here.

Of course, with OpenFlow, it is trivial to completely replace all the rules. So you could simply just delete the existing ones and send out a new set of rules with the corrected priority values.